# Where does image_utils come from in Tensorflow TPU data converter tool example?

Tags: tensorflow, tpu, image-classification

I'm trying to convert an image classification dataset for use with Cloud TPU (as seen [here](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/classification-data-conversion)) and in the examples that they give, there is this file (https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu/blob/master/tools/data_converter/image_classification/image_classification_data.py). Line 44 there is this import:

```
import image_utils as image
```

I cannot find where this image_utils comes from. Help very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `image_utils` you refer to is defined [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu/blob/master/tools/data_converter/image_utils.py).